# Retrieve list of users/groups that have access to a network folder and its subfolders?

Tags: windows-server-2003, query, file-permissions

One of our users is requesting a list of the users and groups that have access to two folders on the network, as well as all of the subfolders of both of these folders. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of subfolders. Is there an automated way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use get-acl from powershell:

```
get-childitem -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer}|get-acl
```

this:

1. gets the directory list (recursivly)
2. if it so happens that the item on the pipeline is a container (folder)...
3. retrieve the ACL list

Comment: Would this specify permissions on just the folders and sub-folders, or will it also list file permissions? (The former is what I'm after)

Comment: See the edit for details

Answer (score 0):

`cacls.exe` should do what you require, its a bit hard to read but that comes with the territory of doing such a task on command line.

Comment: Unfortunately, using cacls would be far too cumbersome and time consuming for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the [SolarWinds tool](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/permissions_analyzer_for_active_directory/) for this, though it's not great at recursion.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'm currently running Systernals AccessEnum, which might be too granular. It appears that it's listing permissions for every file within the folders and subfolders, and not just the folder and subfolder permissions.